# No pom found while creating new project from archetype

Tags: maven

I am trying to execute this :

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple -DartifactId=simple - DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

but it shows this error:

```
C:\TPMaven>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple -DartifactId=simple - DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.090 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-20T17:28:05+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/108M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\TPMaven). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. ->     [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

What's wrong with my maven statement?

Comment: what version of maven?

Comment: You need to specify -DarchetypeGroupId=... -DarchetypeArtifactId=... -DarchetypeVersion=...

Comment: `- DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook ` The space between the dash and DpackageName may be the culprit. BTW, please title your question appropriately.

Comment: I've edited the title to make it more relevant to the actual problem you're having. Please try to be more specific in future.

Answer (score 11):

The right code should be:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple -DartifactId=simple -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

If you use Win, running the code above in cmd.exe is ok.

If you run the code in PowerShell, please use the code below:

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple" "-DartifactId=simple" "-DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook" "-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

---

There are two errors in your code:

> mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple -DartifactId=simple - DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT"

1. > - DpackageName

should be

```
-DpackageName
```

2. > -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT"

should be

```
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in between one of your command line arguments. Running your command:

```
    acanby@PANAMERA /c/projects/mvntest $ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple -DartifactId=simple - DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.072 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-21T15:20:41+10:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (c:\projects\mvntest). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory
. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Fixing the `- DpackageName=...` part to `-DpackageName=...`:

```
acanby@host /c/projects/mvntest$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook.simple -DartifactId=simple -DpackageName=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
```